# Integrate $ \int dr(dr+2r)\left(1-\frac{r+\frac{dr}{2}}{r_0}\right) $

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

How can I integrate the following?

$$ \int dr(dr+2r)\left(1-\frac{r+\frac{dr}{2}}{r_0}\right) $$

Where $r_{0}$ is a constant and $r=[0, r_{0}]$

Comment: $dr$ is that the differential outside brackets but $d\cdot r$ within? It's confusing to say the least.

Comment: You can't, your expression is not an integral (in any known variant of integration)

Comment: $dr$ is intended as differential
@achille hui I guess I made a wrong formulation then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice,  $$\int dr(dr+2r)\left(1-\frac{r+\frac{dr}{2}}{r_0}\right)$$
$$=\int ((dr)^2+2r\ dr)\left(1-\frac{2r+dr}{2r_0}\right)$$
as $dr\to 0$ hence, neglecting $(dr)^2$
$$=\int 2r\ dr\left(\frac{2r_0-2r-dr}{2r_0}\right)$$

$$=\frac{1}{r_0}\int r\left(2(r_0-r)dr-(dr)^2\right)$$
neglecting $(dr)^2$

$$=\frac{1}{r_0}\int 2r(r_0-r)dr$$
$$=\frac{1}{r_0}\int 2rr_0\ dr-\frac{1}{r_0}\int 2r^2\ dr$$
$$=2\int r\ dr-\frac{2}{r_0}\int r^2\ dr$$

Comment: Nice work, for understanding what the OP wanted with very little information. +1